# Converting SQL Query to Access Query - SELECT within SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have a query in SQL Server that I am trying to convert to a query in MS-Access 2003. The query is designed to be used as the basis for a report. The report has two fields .. 'Cases Assigned' and 'Cases Closed'.

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM CaseDetail 
WHERE CaseAssignedDate Between '1/1/2008' AND '1/1/2009') as 'Cases Assigned',
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM CaseDetail 
WHERE CaseClosedDate BETWEEN '1/1/2008' AND '1/1/2009') as 'Cases Closed'
```

I am having difficulty using the SQL in Access 2003. I have replaced the `'` characters with `#` for Access's sake but still no joy. Does Access have a problem with SELECT within SELECT statements? The error I get from Access is less than helpful.

```
Reserved error (-3205); there is no message for this error
```

Also, what if the SQL statement was such that data needed to be obtained from more than one table. For example ...

```
SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM AssignedCases
WHERE CaseAssignedDate Between '1/1/2008' AND '1/1/2009') as 'Cases Assigned',
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM ClosedCases
WHERE CaseClosedDate BETWEEN '1/1/2008' AND '1/1/2009') as 'Cases Closed'
```

This works in SQL without issue, but not in Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested queries are allowed in Access as well as in SQL server, but at least in SQL server it requires that you set a dummy alias for your nested query, and all columns in your nested query need a name. This might have caused the error.

I would suggest following query:

```
SELECT q1.CasesAssigned, q2.CasesClosed
FROM 
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS CasesAssigned
FROM CaseDetail 
WHERE CaseAssignedDate Between '1/1/2008' AND '1/1/2009') as q1,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS CasesClosed
FROM CaseDetail 
WHERE CaseClosedDate BETWEEN '1/1/2008' AND '1/1/2009') as q2
```

Comment: I ran this within Access and it worked! This was ideal for me because I needed to aggregate data from fields that were in separate and un-related tables. This allowed be to collect all aggregates data as a single row result set allowing me to use it as the basis for a report. Thanks @littlegreen!

Comment: "SQL server it requires that you set a dummy alias for your nested query, and all columns in your nested query need a name" -- I think you misread the query: these are scalar subqueries in the `SELECT` clause and there is no requirement for column 'aliases' nor table correlation names. You seem to be talking about derived tables in a `FROM` clause.

Comment: In that case 'as q1' and 'as q2' may be omitted. I cannot test it at the moment but you may well be right.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't a Windows machine to test on at the moment, but something like this should work.

```
SELECT SUM(IIF(CaseAssignedDate 
           BETWEEN #1/1/2008# AND #1/1/2009#, 1, 0)) AS CasesAssigned,
       SUM(IIF(CaseClosedDate 
           BETWEEN #1/1/2008# AND #1/1/2009#, 1, 0)) AS CasesClosed
  FROM CaseDetail
```

In my experience it is generally preferable, where possible, to avoid using subqueries in Access.

---

Edit:
Responding to your comment, I just tested that Access allows this alternative method:

```
SELECT *
  FROM
(
SELECT 'CasesAssigned', COUNT(*) AS Total
  FROM AssignedCases
 WHERE CaseAssignedDate BETWEEN #1/1/2008# AND #1/1/2009#

UNION ALL

SELECT 'ClosedCases', COUNT(*) AS Total
  FROM ClosedCases
 WHERE CaseClosedDate BETWEEN #1/1/2008# AND #1/1/2009#
);
```

---

Edit2:
[littlegreen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831949/converting-sql-query-to-access-query-select-within-select/3832075#3832075) will work if you need a one-row resultset.

Comment: This works if all the data is coming from one table. How could it be modified if other tables need to be queried?

Comment: @webworm: please see my edit. I am not so sure that splitting up those data is the best table structure. However, that's another question entirely. Best of luck to you.

Comment: @webworm: littlegreen's answer is ideal, then.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you're getting this error message, but your problem is trying to execute a Select statement without at least a table or query. You'll need some sort of 'dummy' table with just one record to accomplish this.

```
SELECT  
    (SELECT COUNT(*)  
     FROM CaseDetail  
     WHERE CaseAssignedDate Between '1/1/2008' AND '1/1/2009'
    ) as 'Cases Assigned', 
    (SELECT COUNT(*)  
     FROM CaseDetail  
     WHERE CaseClosedDate BETWEEN '1/1/2008' AND '1/1/2009'
    ) as 'Cases Closed' 
FROM DummyTableWithOneRecord;
```

Comment: Could you explain why this "DummyTableWithOneRecord" is needed? Seems like a bit of a hack. Does the record have to contain a certain number of fields? Specific names?

Comment: I should explain what I meant by hack. Not hack in a bad way but more that I really didn't understand how it was working. I tried your suggestion but I got a NULL result set back. No rows and no field.

Comment: + for actually answering the question i.e. Select statement requires a table.

Comment: @webworm: "why this "DummyTableWithOneRecord" is needed? Seems like a bit of a hack." -- In Standard SQL, a `SELECT` requires a table. For a change, Access has got it right :) It is SQL Server that provides the "hack" by allowing you to use `SELECT` in absence of a table e.g. `SELECT 1;` is valid on SQL Server and actually returns a resultset too, but violates the Standard ...or extends it, if you prefer :) To do it properly (or on Access) you would need `SELECT 1 FROM AnyTable;` assuming AnyTable has exactly one row or `SELECT DISTINCT 1 FROM AnyTable;` assuming AnyTable has at least one row.

Comment: @Jeff O: "`Select 1 as TheOne;` will work in [ACE] 2007" -- indeed and is equivalent to my `SELECT 1 FROM AnyTable;`, assuming that `TheOne` has but one row.

Comment: @onedaywhen - no TheOne is a column alias and not a table.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a query which works in SQL Server, create an Access pass-through query which uses that query (in SQL Server) and returns the result set to Access.

Alternatively, create a SQL Server view based on that SELECT statement and link to the view from Access.

Since it already works in SQL Server, I don't see any added value from re-creating the query in Access.

Comment: Well, in Access it certainly can't be an OUTER JOIN!

Answer (score 0):

3205 error is Too many crosstab column headers .

Does this query solution for you:

```
SELECT 'Cases Asssigned' as Type, COUNT(*) 
FROM CaseDetail 
WHERE CaseAssignedDate Between '1/1/2008' AND '1/1/2009'
UNION
SELECT 'Cases Closed'as Type, COUNT(*) 
FROM CaseDetail 
WHERE CaseClosedDate BETWEEN '1/1/2008' AND '1/1/2009')
```

result will in two rows instead of one.

Comment: Since this will be the basis for a report, is there a way to return the results as 1 row with multiple columns?